# Linq to Sql : how to get data - one to many

Tags: c#, sql, linq

My app in ASP.NET C#. I use Linq to Sql, look the picuture

[image]

// 5 data talbe :

```
// Unit table

     id |   name    | unit_type_id          Unit_type   
       -------------------------                    
        1 | Unit 1  |     1                     id   |  name
        2 | Unit 2  |     1                     -------------   
        3 | Unit 3  |     1                     1    |  Type 1
        4 | Unit 4  |     2                     2    |  Type 2
        5 | Unit 5  |     1                     3    |  Type 3
        6 | Unit 6  |     3     




 //Tool table                                // tool_type   table

    id  |   name    | tool_type_id              id   |  name
    ----------------------------            ------------------- 
    1   |   Tool 1  |     1                     1    |  Tool_type 1
    2   |   Tool 2  |     2                     2    |  Tool_type 2
    3   |   Tool 3  |     1                     3    |  Tool_type 3
    4   |   Tool 4  |     2         
    5   |   Tool 5  |     3
```

//unit_tool table

```
unit_id | tool_id
    ---------------
    1   |    1
    2   |    1
    1   |    2
    1   |    3
    2   |    2
    2   |    3
    3   |    3
    3   |    2
```

I want to use linq to sql in C# to get data like

// Table data i want to get

```
Unit name  |  Unit type name  | Tool name
-------------------------------------------------
Unit 1     | Type 1           | tool 1, tool 2, tool 3
Unit 2     | Type 1           | tool 1, tool 2, tool 3
Unit 3     | Type 1           | tool 2, tool 3
Unit 4     | Type 2           | 
Unit 5     | Type 1           | 
Unit 6     | Type 3           |
```

My code be low

// Create new class

```
public class unit_list
    {
        //Unit name
        public string unit_name { get; set; }
        // Unit type name
        public string unit_type_name { get; set; }
        // Tool name
        public string tool_name { get; set; }
    }
```

// Function get data

```
protected void show_unit()
{
    // Create datacontext
    for_testDataContext db = new for_testDataContext();
    //Query data
    IQueryable<unit_list> CourseList = from cl in db.units
                                        select new unit_list()
                                        {
                                            unit_name = cl.name,
                                            unit_type_name = cl.unit_type.name,
                                            tool_name = // how to get data like "tool1, tool 2, tool 3"
                                        };

}
```

Comment: Please move your "answer" from below up to the question - you can always edit your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write something like this (assuming all the relationships are set up correctly in Linq):

```
select new unit_list()
{
    unit_name = cl.name,
    unit_type_name = cl.unit_type.name,
    tool_name = string.Join(", ", 
        cl.unit_tools.Select(ut => ut.tool.name).ToArray()
    )
};
```

In other words..

1. Get the one-to-many relationship to **unit_tools**
2. Select the corresponding row in **tool** and select the *name* column
3. Join to get a single comma-separated string

Comment: Error 'unit' does not contain a definition for 'unit_tools' and no extension method 'unit_tools' accepting a first argument of type 'unit' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Is there problem in Linq context?

Comment: Does **unit_tool** (or anything along those lines) appear in intellisense?  It seems like the foreign keys are set up correctly, given the diagram you posted.  Maybe as Tieson T. suggests, you just need to regenerate the Linq classes from the database.

Comment: I just set foreing keys for unit_id and tool_id but nothing change

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any foreign keys set up, which means you don't get automatic "navigation properties" with your mapped entities. You will have to either update your database and then regenerate the mapping, or add them yourself using the toolbox.

**EDIT:**

Okay, let's run down a very short checklist.

1. *Are primary and foreign keys set and associated properly in the schema (your database)?* This is important, as this is what the
   sqlmetal executable uses to generate your object context.
2. *Do the associations in your model point to the correct properties in the parent and child entities?* You can check this by clicking on
   an association between two objects in the model viewer and then expanding the `Properties`
   pane. Expand the `Child` and `Parent` properties and verify they are not
   empty.

If you've done everything right so far, clicking on the association between `Unit_Tool` and `Unit` should show a `Child` property called `Units`.

If you're missing an association, you can add one by:

1. Clicking on the `Association` tool in the `Toolbox`.
2. Clicking on the object which defines the **primary** key.
3. Clicking on the object that holds the **foreign** key.

This will bring up a dialog box that should be pretty self-explanatory.

HTH.

**EDIT:**

Solved this by playing around with your existing code (thanks for the upload). The problem was super simple, but not exactly obvious: **you need to have an identifier column in each table, or Linq-to-SQL doesn't create the child collection reference in the data context.** So, since you're using `unit_tool` as just a pivot table (perfectly acceptable), without a unique ID on each row, you don't get a "navigation property." To fix this, just add a primary key field (you don't ever have to actually use it - it's just for the ORM) to the `unit_tool` table, recreate the entity mapping, and *viola!*, your query will work as-is.

I have to say, this wasn't obvious at first blush. I haven't ever had this problem, since I always create a unique identifier out of habit...

Comment: "or add them yourself using the toolbox" : can you explain more? (i'm beginer, this is the second time i use linq to sql )

Comment: If you've changed your database, I recommend deleting all the existing objects in the model and dragging the new/updated tables into the designer, **AFTER** performing a refresh on the connection.

Comment: Hi Tieson T, i checked many things follow your explain, but nothing change, still error "Error 'unit' does not contain a definition for 'unit_tools' and no extension method 'unit_tools' accepting a first argument of type 'unit' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Is there problem in Linq context?"

Comment: Is this something where you can drop the project into Dropbox or something similar? I really have no other suggestions without seeing more code.

Comment: I uploaded my code and database to Mediafire. Here is the link http://www.mediafire.com/?rdlca58m9yfmeju

Comment: Hi Tieson T, Thanks for strong support. :) very simple and i'm very stupid.